# Laravel eager loading with constraints

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

So my model has 2 simple relationships. Then eager loading works perfectly like this:

```
Entry::with('author', 'lastModifiedBy')->...;
```

But say I want to add a new relationship that takes a constraint. For example:

```
public function foo() {
    return $this->hasOne('Foo')->latest('id');
}
```

Then to eager load this relationship, Laravel suggests doing it like so:

```
Entry::with(array('foo' => function($query) use ($id) {
    $query->where('user_id', $id);
}))->...;
```

But if I want to include my `author` and `lastModifiedBy` relationships, I end up having to do:

```
Entry::with(array(
    'foo' => function($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('user_id', $id);
    },
   'author' => function() { },
   'lastModifiedBy' => function() { }
))->...;
```

I have to give those 2 relationships an empty function. Is there a simpler way to do this without the ugliness of these empty functions?

Comment: Here are the docs on constraining eager load relationships in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The empty functions are not necessary. Laravel is smart enough to be able to work with a mixed array of relations with constraints and such without them.

```
Entry::with(array(
    'foo' => function($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('user_id', $id);
    },
    'author',
    'lastModifiedBy'
))->...;
```

#### How it works

Here's how Laravel distinguishes between the two:

in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder@parseRelations`

```
foreach ($relations as $name => $constraints)
{
    // If the "relation" value is actually a numeric key, we can assume that no
    // constraints have been specified for the eager load and we'll just put
    // an empty Closure with the loader so that we can treat all the same.
    if (is_numeric($name))
    {
        $f = function() {};
        list($name, $constraints) = array($constraints, $f);
    }
```

As the comment describes, Laravel actually adds the empty closure by itself if the key of the array item is numeric.

Answer (score 1):

You don't neew those empty functions. You can directly put the relations on them.

```
Entry::with(array(
    'foo' => function($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('user_id', $id);
    },
    'author', 'lastModifiedBy'
))->...;
```

Or alternatively you can put those on nested with method.

```
Entry::with(array(
    'foo' => function($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('user_id', $id);
    }
))
->with('author', 'lastModifiedBy')->...;
```